# How do I control progress bar with converter time?

Tags: c#, forms, backgroundworker, video-processing

Video Converter is performing the process.This converter is doing mp3 to mp4 or the other format transformation. I'm doing this via C # Form. I want to use the progress bar to show the user the progress of the process. According to my research, I had to use a backgroundworker. And I used, but it is not working. Where is the my fault? Code is here;

```
  private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Convert();
          //  backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, e.Result);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
        }
            //   Bitrate();
    }
```

Please help me ?

Controlling the progress bar with the backgroundworker made my project difficult after a certain place. In this case, I decided to move on async structure, I built the architecture on the async structure. But this time I did not know how to control the progress bar under the async structure. What are your ideas and opinions on this issue? Async codes my button event;

but it not to work? What can ı do?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
}
 private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 1;
        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
          {
              progressBar1.Value = percent;
          });
         await Convert();

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting a cross thread error? Or is it just not updating?

Comment: no I am not getting any errors. Program is running but progress bar is not making progress

Comment: Might be because you're not updating the progress bar on the UI thread, try the answer below

Comment: works but after being converted; and it doesn't move at the right rate with processing speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the background workers [`ReportProgress`-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress)? It exists for exactly this purpose.

Subscribe to the [`ProgressChanged`-event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) and update the progress-bar from there.

```
// Wherever you instanciate your BackgroundWorker
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += (o, e) => progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

```
// Your DoWork method
private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Convert();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
    // Bitrate();
}
```

Since these steps are in percent you should also set the minimum and maximum value of the progress bar. You already set the value and the step but you shouldn't do it in the `DoWork`-method. Do it somewhere else, for example just before calling `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()`.
Also note that I made the for loop 1-100 since we're working with percent. You could also do 0-99 and report i+1.

```
progressBar1.Value = 0;
progressBar1.Step = 1;
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
```

Edit 1:

As mentionend in the comments, I forgot the possibility of creating a `BackgroundWorker` with the winforms designer. In that case, you should use the constructor of your Form (or UserControl) to subscribe to the `ProcessChanged` event.

Edit 2:

To answer your follow-up question on resetting the ProgressBar after the worker has completed, I will show you two possible solutions.

```
// You can directly subscribe to RunWorkerCompleted using a lambda like before
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) => progressBar1.Value = 0;
```

```
// Or you can use a method (useful if you have other things to do when the worker is done)
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    // some more stuff
}

// Subscribe to RunWorkerCompleted with this method
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

In both solutions, the subscription to `RunWorkerCompleted` should be put right before or after the subscription to `ProgressChanged` (this means in the constructor in this case).

Comment: where exactly do I have to define this code?
// Wherever you instanciate your BackgroundWorker
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += (o, e) => progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

Comment: I just realized that you might have used the winforms designer to create your BackgroundWorker, is that correct? If so, you should use the constructor of your form. Be sure to put the line after `InitializeComponents` otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I forgot to mention you for the notification: @ZeynepBaran

Comment: Yes I'm using Windows Form, thank you very much for your help, one last question, if I want the progress bar to be reset after the process is complete, can I set the value of the progressbar to zero in the backgroundworker's RunWorkerCompleted event? @Joelius

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. I'll edit my answer to include that. I would appreciate if you could upvote (or even accept) my answer since, althought possible, the currently accepted answer is definitely not the right way to solve your issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer @ZeynepBaran, let me know if it worked :)

Comment: The progress bar works but starts late, and every time it progresses; my convert function is defined at the end of the process I want to give the message gives. And this process goes from 1 to 100, which we also define for great imitation. Although the conversion process has already been completed, the progress bar continues. @Joelius

Comment: _It starts late_ is probably because the for loop starts at 0 instead of 1. _this process goes from 1 to 100_ well yea it should because it's in percent which makes perfect sense for a progress bar. If you have more or less than 100 steps you can easily calculate that into percent, that's actually how you're supposed to do it. You also mention the progress bar continuing after the conversion process has been completed.. this shouldn't happen if you use my code. Have you tried debugging the program to find the error?

Comment: "If you have more or less than 100 steps you can easily calculate that into percent, that's actually how you're supposed to do it. "How can I do that? And yes ı did

Comment: As long as you have a known number of steps you can do simple percent math: `CurrentStep * 100 / AllSteps` where `AllSteps` is the amount of steps required for the whole operation. Hope that helps. You also mention that you debugged the program.. what are your findings / where do you still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the `progressBar1.PerformStep();` on the UI thread by Invoking it, like below

```
BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
});
```

And remove the `Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: works but after being converted; and it doesn't move at the right rate with processing speed

Comment: While this is a possible solution, it's not at all how you're supposed to do it. Take a look at the answer below. You should also check out the [documentation for `BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) where you can find pretty much the same things I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons; technically I cannot run progress bar usage as a task or async without backgroundworker. Therefore, what progress should I make based on the converter processing time?
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the progress bar with the backgroundworker made my project difficult after a certain place. In this case, I decided to move on async structure, I built the architecture on the async structure. But this time I did not know how to control the progress bar under the async structure. What are your ideas and opinions on this issue?
Async codes my button event;

but it not to work? What can ı do?

```
  private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 1;
        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
          {
              progressBar1.Value = percent;
          });
         await Convert();

    }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    }
```